# iOS State Restoration with custom container view controller (MMDrawerController)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, state-restoration

**Setup**

I have a sliding menu custom container view controller ([MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)) controlling a center view controller and a slide out left menu/drawer. Just like the Facebook app and hundreds of others.

Opening the drawer on the left and tapping a menu item replaces the center view controller.

**What's Working**

If I open the app, press a button on the first center view controller (which changes the background color), I can kill the app and successfully restore the background color. Perfect.

**What's Not Working**

If I choose another center vc to load (by opening up the menu/drawer and selecting a menu option) and then kill the app, the app won't restore to that view controller.

**What I'm Doing**

In my parent view controller I'm encoding the left and center view controllers so I can recreate them on restore.

```
- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.centerViewController forKey:@"centerVC"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.leftDrawerViewController forKey:@"leftDrawerVC"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}

- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    // if I don't change the center view controller, these values
    // get logged out as expected
    NSLog(@"leftDrawer: %@", [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"leftDrawerVC"]);
    NSLog(@"center: %@", [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"centerVC"]);
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

In the flow where I change the color on the first center view controller, during decoding I can get back the center and left View Controllers successfully. However in the flow where I select a new center vc to load, during decoding those objects are nil.

How do I set up my custom container view controller to properly encode references to it's children in a way that I'm guaranteed to get them back while decoding?

**UPDATE 1**

Using the [restorationArchiveTool](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) I inspected the archive after running through the scenario that doesn't restore properly, and the archive does in fact contain the hierarchy of encoded objects that I'd expect. I still can't figure out though why those previously encoded view controllers end up being null during decoding.

**UPDATE 2**
If you look at the comments section of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/djibouti33/6124370), you can see that all the proper encode/decode calls seem to be happening on saving and restoring. I'm wondering if in my app delegate, when i initially set up my root view controller (the instance of mmdrawercontroller) if I'm somehow clobbering the state restoration? Here's what I'm doing:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavController *centerNav = [[UINavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[FeaturedViewController new]];
    centerNav.restorationIdentifier = @"centerNav";
    UINavigationController *leftDrawerNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[LeftDrawerViewController new]];
    leftDrawerNavController.restorationIdentifier = @"leftDrawerNav";

    MMDrawerController *drawerViewController = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerNav leftDrawerViewController:leftDrawerNavController];

    // no restoration class, since this will always be created before state restoration resumes, and therefore will be found implicitly
    [drawerViewController setRestorationIdentifier:@"mmDrawer"];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = drawerViewController;
    self.window.restorationIdentifier = NSStringFromClass([UIWindow class]);
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done similar with MMDrawerController and believe the problem is that you are not providing UIKit with a way to create all of the possible center view controllers when it is restoring state.  Note that when you encode a controller, all that gets saved is the restoration ID for that controller.  To be restored when you next start the app UIKit needs to be able to obtain an instance of the controller -- it won't create one itself.  It will try various methods to obtain said instance, as listed here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH11-SW10

Your app may create the default center controller every time (either via a storyboard or manually) so that one works.  For others you probably need to either implement a restoration class or implement `application:viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder:` in your delegate and have it return a new instance of the right type.

Comment: If you check out the comments section of this gist (https://gist.github.com/djibouti33/6124370) you can see that all the proper encode/decode calls seem to be happening to the appropriate view controllers. Namely, my SearchVC is getting encoded, and upon restoration, it's being sent +viewControllerWithRestorationIdentiferPath as well as -decodeRestoratbleStateWithCoder. The problem here is that when my MMDrawerController is restored, the previously encoded view controllers (left and center) are null. Technically those are both NavControllers, but they have restorationIDs so I should be fine.

Comment: This is very similar to my app. At times when implementing this I was also getting nils when decoding the center controller, and it was because UIKit didn't know how to create/find the center nav controller. Does your app have a method of providing an instance of the search nav controller when restoring? I'd guess your application:viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder: is being asked for it and returning nil. In my app I always create both alternative controllers (the navs and their children) in willFinishLaunching, and my delegate will provide them as requested on restore.

Comment: My understanding is that being a built in container controller, there's nothing I have to do with a NavController other than set its restorationID to register it in the chain of restorable objects. As long as it's root view controller (my featuredVC or searchVC) has an ID and a restorationClass, it should know how to rebuild. My application:viewControllerFor... method is actually blank because as I understand things, I've set everything up so that things can either be found implicitly or be recreated as necessary. I added an update above showing my appWillFinishLaunching. Anything glaring?

Comment: And you asked: "Does your app have a method of providing an instance of the search nav controller when restoring?" The initial CenterNavController created in appWillFinish is given an ID of "centerNav" (and it loads the FeaturedVC. When you open the drawer and select a menu item (search), I wrap the SearchController inside a NavController that I give the same restorationID to (centerNav). My app doesn't create anything having to do wtih Search in appWillFinish. I thought I just had to wait for the restore to take care of that.

Comment: It should be easy enough to add application:viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder: and see if UIKit is asking you to create the navigation controller. From my experience I believe it will. Note you don't have to restore its navigation stack, that is indeed all handled by UINavigationController, you just provide an unconfigured instance. (Another difference in my case is I don't give the two nav controllers the same ID, but that's because I always create them both, and it might be fine in your case.)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, could you throw the generic parts of your appWillFinish and the three app delegate state restoration methods into a gist? I'm thinking I don't have the app delegate set up correctly. But, following your advice, I'm logging the identifierPath from app:viewControllerWithRestoration... and I get three calls: (    mmDrawer), (mmDrawer,leftDrawerNav), and (mmDrawer,centerNav). So you're right, it is asking for the centerNav, however, since it's already created in appWillFinishLaunching, I didn't think I needed to create it explicitly.

Comment: I don't actually use application:willEncodeRestorableStateWithCoder: (or decode).  They aren't necessary if the controller hierarchy encodes itself properly (which with your modifications to MMDrawerController should be the case). AFAIK creating the nav controller with the right ID is not enough. You still need to return it when asked in viewControllerWithRestoration.  Did you try that? (A gist is painful for me to sanitise, I'm afraid.)

Comment: Ok, so I'm closer!!!! You're right, I have to return both the left and center nav controllers in order for their children to be restored as well. https://gist.github.com/djibouti33/6129555. Now the only problem I'm seeing is that I'm getting an "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for " both my left and center nav controllers. When my restored Search controller loads in the center, and i open the drawer again, the leftDrawerNavController seems to jump up into position. But, I'm able to restore the nav stack successfully. Incredible!